# Creating a Multi-Step Modal Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[I want to create a multistep modal using this](https://github.com/ngzhian/multi-step-modal)

I this div with classes that is generated dynamically

```
$('.modal-content').append('<div class="modal-body step step-' + key + '" data-step="'+key+'"></div>');
```

Now I want to append an input variable to that div. I'm trying this but I dont get any html nor error (and I can read the console log correctly)

```
$.each(inputs, function (index,input) {
    console.log(input);
    $(".modal-body step step-" + key).append(input);
});
```

**How do I append to a div with multiple classes??**

SNIPPET

```js
var testCaseNames = ['test1', 'test2'];
var inputs = ['test3', 'test4'];

//Modal
var modal = '<form class="modal multi-step" id="creationModal"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"></div><div class="modal-footer"></div>';
//Progress
modal += '';

$.each(testCaseNames, function(key, value) {
  console.log(key + ": " + value);
      console.log(inputs);
      //Headers
      $('.modal-header').append('<h4 class="modal-title step-' + key + '" data-step="' + key + '">' + value + '</h4>');
      //Body
      $('.modal-content').append('<div class="modal-body step step-' + key + '" data-step="' + key + '"></div>');
      $.each(inputs, function(index, input) {
        console.log(input);
        $(".modal-body .step .step-" + key).append(input);
      });
      //Footer Buttons
      $('.modal-footer').append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div>');
      $('.modal-footer').append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary step step-' + key + '" data-step="' + key + '" onclick="sendEvent(\'#creationModal\', 1)">Continue</button>');
      
  $('.modal-content').append('</div></form>');
  $('#modalDiv').empty().append(modal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.ngzhian.com/multi-step-modal/multi-step-modal.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<button type="submit" class="btn btn-rounded btn-success-outline top10" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#creationModal" id="btnSubmit">Create</button>


<div id='modalDiv'></div>

<script>
  sendEvent = function(sel, step) {
    $(sel).trigger('next.m.' + step);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: What is `inputs`? Please show us a complete code sample. Your selector is also incorrect. It would need to be `$(".modal-body.step.step-" + key)` as all the classes are on the same element

Comment: what is `inputs` ? Can you post a `console.log(inputs);` ?

Comment: So I just need the dots? inputs is just a string[]

Comment: Doesnt work with the dots. (No html appended) `<div class="modal-body step step-0" data-step="0">(NO HTML)</div>`

Comment: Yes, you need the dots in the selector. If `inputs` is just an array of strings, then you don't need to loop at all. You can just call `append(inputs.join(''))` once

Comment: @sda please add a full code sample. We cannot help you without it

Comment: Ok I will add all my code.

Comment: I Added my code

Answer (score 1):

To select div with multiple class you should use the following code,

```
$(".modal-body.step.step-" + key).append(input);
```

Comment: change modal var modal = '<form class="modal multi-step" id="creationModal"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"></div><div class="modal-footer"></div></div></form>'; and put the line $('#modalDiv').empty().append(modal);  immediately after  above  var modal=....; intialization. And remove the line  $('.modal-content').append('</div></form>');

Answer (score 1):

The main problem seems to be the missing append at the start :

```
//Modal
var modal = $('<form class="modal multi-step" id="creationModal"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"></div><div class="modal-footer"></div></div></form>');

$('#modalDiv').empty().append(modal);
```

Also the spaces between your classes inside the selector, what mean the selector will search for the childs with those classes instead of the element with class `modal-body+step+step-{key}` if you remove them your selector should be valid :

```
$(".modal-body .step .step-" + key).append(input);
 ______________^____^
```

Should be :

```
$(".modal-body.step.step-" + key).append(input);
```

```js
sendEvent = function(sel, step) {
  $(sel).trigger('next.m.' + step);
}


var testCaseNames = ['test1', 'test2'];
var inputs = ['test3', 'test4'];

//Modal
var modal = $('<form class="modal multi-step" id="creationModal"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"></div><div class="modal-footer"></div></div></form>');

$('#modalDiv').empty().append(modal);

$.each(testCaseNames, function(key, value) {
  //Headers
  $('.modal-header').append('<h4 class="modal-title step-' + key + '" data-step="' + key + '">' + value + '</h4>');
  //Body
  $('.modal-content').append('<div class="modal-body step step-' + key + '" data-step="' + key + '"></div>');
  $.each(inputs, function(index, input) {
    $(".modal-body.step.step-" + key, modal).append(input);
  });
  //Footer Buttons
  $('.modal-footer').append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div>');
  $('.modal-footer').append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary step step-' + key + '" data-step="' + key + '" onclick="sendEvent(\'#creationModal\', 1)">Continue</button>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.ngzhian.com/multi-step-modal/multi-step-modal.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-rounded btn-success-outline top10" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#creationModal" id="btnSubmit">Create</button>

<div id='modalDiv'></div>
```

Comment: "working". it's supposed to be a step modal not all in the same place :P

Comment: I mean I've fixed the main problem asked in your OP, you could continue from here by adding the styles `block/none` so not all the divs will shows at the same time ...

Comment: do you see the link I posted? It's a already made library. It should work just like that. It works if you put the html directly instead of jquery generated

Comment: It's not, if you inspect the code in https://www.ngzhian.com/multi-step-modal/ you could see the inline styles if you remove them the example will end up like your with all shown divs at the same time.

Comment: but he's only importing bootstrap. That's what I have on this snipett

Comment: You could post a new detailed question that ask for this specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Once you "append" your data to a div, it gets added to the DOM as text rather than a DOM element. , Try something like this

```
    // Get the element you want to add your new element before or after
var target = document.querySelector('#some-div');

// Create the new element
// This can be any valid HTML element: p, article, span, etc...
var div = document.createElement('div');

// Add content to the new element
div.innerHTML = 'Your content, markup, etc.';

// You could also add classes, IDs, and so on
// div is a fully manipulatable DOM Node

// Insert the element before our target element
target.parentNode.insertBefore( div, target );

// Insert the element after our target element
target.parentNode.insertBefore( div, target.nextSibling );
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are trying to append to a modal which is not shown yet in DOM.

Just Place your this line

```
$('#modalDiv').empty().append(modal);
```

Right After this line

```
var modal = '<form class="modal multi-step" id="creationModal"><div 
class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header">
</div><div class="modal-footer"></div>';
//Progress
modal += '';
```

it should look like

```
modal += '';
$('#modalDiv').empty().append(modal);
```

It will solve your problem