# Using Javascript to create html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[I want to create a multistep modal using this](https://github.com/ngzhian/multi-step-modal) As you can see the imports are the same and the HTML is the same. **The only difference is that I'm doing it using javascript.**

The problem is that my modal is not in steps but instead it's in all in the same page.

What is causing this? Is there a way to execute their javascript file after I run mine? I dont know... it seems like it's not using their js file.

```js
$("body").on('click', '#btnSubmit', function(e) {

  var testCaseNames = ['test1', 'test2'];
  var inputs = ['test3', 'test4'];

  //Modal
  var modal = '<form class="modal multi-step" id="creationModal"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"></div><div class="modal-step-body"></div><div class="modal-footer"></div></div></form>';
  
   $('#modalDiv').empty().append(modal);
  
  $.each(testCaseNames, function(key, value) {
    console.log(key + ": " + value);
    console.log(inputs);
    //Headers
    $('.modal-header').append('<h4 class="modal-title step-' + key + '" data-step="' + key + '">' + value + '</h4>');
    //Body
    $('.modal-step-body').append('<div class="modal-body step step-' + key + '" data-step="' + key + '"></div>');
    $.each(inputs, function(index, input) {
      console.log(input);
      $(".modal-body.step.step-" + key).append(input);
    });
    //Footer Buttons
    $('.modal-footer').append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div>');
    $('.modal-footer').append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary step step-' + key + '" data-step="' + key + '" onclick="sendEvent(\'#creationModal\', ' + key + ')">Continue</button>');


  });
});

sendEvent = function() {
  $('#creationModal').trigger('next.m.2');
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button type="submit" class="btn btn-rounded btn-success-outline top10" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#creationModal" id="btnSubmit">Create</button>


<div id='modalDiv'></div>

<script src="https://www.ngzhian.com/multi-step-modal/multi-step-modal.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why dont you stop after one question and wait for the right answer?
you have posted the same question multiple times.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48185455/creating-a-multi-step-modal-using-javascript#48185455

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48184609/creating-a-multi-step-modal-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

$.each is like a for loop. So you are just adding all the steps in one go. You need to call them one after another on button click or whatever you are using.

e.g.

```
function modalStep(int step){
    ...
}
```

and you will need something like a next button where you add onclick="modalStep(1)" or something like that.

you can also use a counter outside of your click function. for every click you increment the counter and show the next step.

edit (untested, only to show you the idea):

```
var testCaseNames = ['test1', 'test2'];
var inputs = ['test3', 'test4'];

//Modal
var modal = '<form class="modal multi-step" id="creationModal"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"></div><div class="modal-step-body"></div><div class="modal-footer"></div></div></form>';

var counter = 0;

function showModal(key, value) {
    console.log(key + ": " + value);
    console.log(inputs);
    //Headers
    $('.modal-header').append('<h4 class="modal-title step-' + key + '" data-step="' + key + '">' + value + '</h4>');
    //Body
    $('.modal-step-body').append('<div class="modal-body step step-' + key + '" data-step="' + key + '"></div>');
    $.each(inputs, function(index, input) {
      console.log(input);
      $(".modal-body.step.step-" + key).append(input);
    });
    //Footer Buttons
    $('.modal-footer').append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div>');
    $('.modal-footer').append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary step step-' + key + '" data-step="' + key + '" onclick="sendEvent(\'#creationModal\', ' + key + ')">Continue</button>');

  }

$("body").on('click', '#btnSubmit', function(e) {

   $('#modalDiv').empty().append(modal);  
   showModal(counter, testCaseNames[counter]);
   counter = (counter+1)%testCaseNames.length;

   console.log("counter: "+counter);
});
```

Comment: I dont think so. Their html is all the steps in the same body and h4 in the same header. Please take a look at their html structure.

Comment: I'm referring to  $.each(testCaseNames, function(key, value) {

Comment: Yeah I'm very bad at this. I cant really see the problem. If I dont add all the steps at once how will I do it?

Comment: sorry, only just saw your ask for help. I've added an example showing how the counter updates every click and this changes what is shown. I'm very tired right now, have not tested anything and am sure it will not work. But I hope you can see the idea of it.